# Why doesn't Drupal use my block.tpl.php?

Tags: blocks, theming

I want my Drupal 7 theme to use a custom block.tpl.php for my navigation bar (Defined: regions[navigation] = Navigation bar). So I copied block.tpl.php from the block module to my theme directory and tried to give it different names (following different guides on the web). None of them seemed to work. 
Then I wanted to make sure it was a naming problem so I changed the name back to block.tpl.php and changed its contents (removed the h2-tag for the title). I reloaded my site but nothing happened so there must be another problem.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thank

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you just need to clear Drupal's caches.

Template file implementations are cached in the theme registry so you need to clear it for new files/theme functions to get picked up.

You can do so either at http://mysite.com/admin/config/development/performance or by using [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know which name must have the template for block (or regions, or other elements) you could try [Devel Themer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer).

Comment: I would insist you to use devel themer module and find the correct template name instead of having a try at all the names.